# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop, startx opens up blank screen

Tags: 18.04, login, lightdm

I am stuck in a login loop on Ubuntu 18.04. I already checked the permissions/ownership of the ***.Xauthority***, ***.ICEauthority*** and ***/tmp*** folder. I tried setting to from lightdm to gdm3. I am still stuck in a login loop.

I also tried running `startx` using the terminal logged-in as the user but it just ends in a blank screen. What are the options that are possible for me and how can I diagnose this? I also tried looking at ***.xsession-errors*** which is just filled with setting environment variable message and no error message.

I tried and fixed the following, and still could not log in

```
$ ls -lah | grep Xauthority
-rw-------   1 isoya isoya   52 Mar  2 12:35 ./Xauthority
$ ls -lah | grep ICEauthority
-rw-------   1 isoya isoya  40K Mar  2 12:16 ./ICEauthority
$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root 4096 Mar  2 14:32 /tmp
```

Here are my xorg log files if it helps:

- [xorg.1.log](https://pastebin.com/ZzhZZNjd)
- [xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/EwfPFgg7)

Likewise [here](https://www.cnet.com/products/toshiba-l745-s4310/) is the system specs.

Comment: Login using a terminal and `df -hl` (disk free, human output & local drives only) to check you have some space in $HOME (your user directory).  GUI's need to create work-files which are created in $HOME, and if there is insufficient space to create them, login fails & you're logged out (no message).

Comment: [df output](https://pastebin.com/5rUzVdKh)

Comment: I don't see a separate /home partition, but if I was in your position I'd check you have inodes free next, ie. add a '-i' to the `df` command; if there are no problems there - this is not your problem.

Comment: should there be a separate /home partition?

Comment: No, it's just a choice (with pro's & con's like everything).

Comment: @DepChemical Glad to hear that you solved the problem. Since this is an Q&A site, please don't add solved in title and solution in body. Instead write the fix/solution as an answer and accept that answer after 48 hours of posting this question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my first question here and I just haphazardly posted without reading the rules. Will do so next time and will update with a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> and login into the shell.
2. Execute `ls -lA`

If you see the line

```
-rw-------  1 root root   53 Nov 29 10:19 .Xauthority
```

then you need to execute the following command:

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
```

and try logging in (you may also need to do the same for *.ICEauthority*).

Else, do

```
ls -ld /tmp
```

Check for the first 10 letters in the left: they should be: `drwxrwxrwt`

```
drwxrwxrwt 15 root root 4096 Nov 30 04:17 /tmp
```

Else, you would be required to execute this command:

```
sudo chmod a+wt /tmp
```

and check again.

If not both, I'd recommend you either execute: `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

or uninstall, reinstall it.

Now press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> until you reach the login screen again, and restart.

Let us know the update via the comments section.

Comment: I already tried those before:

```
isoya@oldFuck:~$ ls -lah | grep Xauthority
-rw-------   1 isoya isoya   52 Mar  2 12:35 ./Xauthority
isoya@oldFuck:~$ ls -lah | grep ICEauthority
-rw-------   1 isoya isoya  40K Mar  2 12:16 ./ICEauthority
isoya@oldFuck:~$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 12 root root 4096 Mar  2 14:32 /tmp
```